# How to use rsync to make a copy of a huge source split into two destinations?

Tags: rsync

I have 3 drives. For this purpose, we will call them A, B and C respectively.

A is 2 TB

B is 1 TB

C is 500 GB

I have already run

```
rsync -avz -progress A B
```

Now B is full and I want to move/copy what is **not** already on B from A to C

It really doesnt matter to me what happens to what is on A as I will reformat anyways.

Comment: You want to move it, or you want to copy it?

Comment: I just want to copy it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a list of all the files on B, say with the the `find` command by going to that drive and running:

```
$ find . > files-on-b.xt
```

Then when you `rsync` from A to C, specify that list in the `--exclude-from` parameter:

```
$ rsync -avz --exclude-from=files-on-b.txt A C
```

You may need to futz with the prefixes in the list to makes sure it matches the format/relative directory that rsync is expecting from an exclude list. Always a good idea to run rsync with the `-n` option to see what it's about to do without actually doing it.

See [rsync man page](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) and [this helpful blog post](http://blog.troyastle.com/2011/11/using-exclude-from-in-rsync.html) for more on `--exclude-from`.

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the `--compare-dest` option. This saves some time and space, as you don’t have to enumerate the whole contents of the first destination, and will work incrementally with many targets. Here’s how it works: After copying the contents from A to B, you run:

```
rsync -avz --compare-dest=/path/to/B /path/to/A/ /path/to/C/
```

rsync will use the contents of B to see what it has to transfer to C to make the copy of A complete. Anything which is already in B won’t be transferred. Note that absolute paths for --compare-dest are required, otherwise the path is taken as relative to the destination.

If you in any event have to split your destination further, you can compare to multiple previous targets by adding more `--compare-dest` arguments.

Comment: The only drawback I see to this approach is that you have to have all drives mounted, whereas with enumerating the contents of the drives you have filled only needs to be once and then those drives can be offline when you do subsequent syncs...